# How to stop mint flavor dying when cooking?

Tags: flavor, meatballs, mint

I notice albondigas recipes involve adding chopped mint leaves to the meatballs. Whenever I do this the minty smell is amazing coming from the freshly rolled uncooked balls however after cooking I cant taste the mint at all, I have used a LOT of mint but even so I still cant taste it. Having read that the mint flavor fades when exposed to heat, how would the meatballs be cooked whilst retaining the flavor? 
At the moment I brown them in the pan with a bit of oil then add them to the sauce and cook them for about 20 minutes.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

While it is true that the mint flavor will fade with cooking, it is still there to some degree.  I bet you would be able to identify the difference if you left it out.  However, whenever you want to highlight a fresh herb, such a mint, it is good practice to chop some of that herb at the last possible moment before serving, and garnish your finished product.  That will greatly enhance the flavor and the aroma.

Comment: I agree, this is also true for basil. While if you need to use rosemary or other aromatic herbs with little water it's better to just cook them (they will release more flavor this way).